Unexpected result returned from useQuery initialData function
I wanted to leverage an existing frequently run, but expensive query, that returns a large set of data to set the initial value for a seldom used query which return a single data point.
To do this, I decide to leverage queryOptions so I could reference the options for the large query in the smaller one.
This looks like this:
export const usersQueryOptions = (
  select: any,
  instance: IPublicClientApplication
) =>
  queryOptions({
    queryKey: [QueryKey.Users],
    queryFn: async () => getUsers(instance),
    select,
    staleTime: 60 * 1000, // 1 minute,
  });

Then I use this in the initialData function of my other hook, where the querykey is ["users", usertoken] denoting a single data point.
export const useUserQuery = (
  userToken: string | null,
  clientUserId: string
) => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const { instance } = useMsal();

  return useQuery({
    queryKey: [QueryKey.Users, userToken],
    queryFn: async () => {
      const apiResult = getUserByClientUserId(instance, clientUserId);
      return apiResult;
    },
    staleTime: 60 * 1000, // 60 Seconds,
    initialData: () => {
      const queryResult = queryClient.getQueryData(
        usersQueryOptions(toUsers, instance).queryKey
      );

      const findResult = queryResult?.data?.find((d) => d.token === userToken);

      // With this line uncommented - expected results are returned
      // Without it, the whole data set from the cache is returned.
      // if (!findResult) return null;

      return findResult;
    },
    initialDataUpdatedAt: () =>
      queryClient.getQueryState([QueryKey.Users])?.dataUpdatedAt,
  });
};

Initially, I did not have the commented out line included. Without this, the result of the hook when used would be the full set of data from the cache instead of a single entry. Can anyone explain what allowed this to happen?
The inferred return type was User | undefined when I added the null check on the findResult variable this changed to User | null and prevented the unexpected result.
The return type of queryFn is Promise<User | null>
I am not primarily a front-end engineer, so I expect I am missing a trick here, but I am confused how a completely wrong type could ever be returned in this scenario.
